# unable to add tap gesture to customized calloutView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a mapview in my app which needs customized calloutView for every map annotations.
Therefore, I have an XIB file for this customized calloutView.
Here is my code for the map view controller

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
    CustomCalloutView *calloutView = (CustomCalloutView *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCalloutView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [calloutView.layer setCornerRadius:10];
    CGRect calloutViewFrame = calloutView.frame;
    calloutViewFrame.origin = CGPointMake(-calloutViewFrame.size.width/2 + 15, -calloutViewFrame.size.height);
    calloutView.frame = calloutViewFrame;

    // some other code such as load images for calloutView

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [calloutView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [view addSubview:calloutView];
}

- (void)handleSingleTap{
    NSLog(@"it works");
}
```

However, the handleSingleTap: has never been called. Instead, every tap on the calloutView will only simply dismiss the calloutView. I also tried to add a button on the calloutView, but tap on it will also cause the calloutView dismissing, rather than calling the button action.

Can anyone help?

**Update**:

I've tried to change the code

```
    [view addSubview:calloutView];
```

to

```
    [self.view addSubview:calloutView];
```

which add the customized calloutView into the main container view rather than the mapView.

Then, it works fine with the tap gesture. Therefore, I think the problem should be caused by the mapView, it seems that mapView passes all the touch event on calloutView to itself. Anyone have ideas regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I worked out the solution finally. We need to have a customized class for the MKAnnotationView to solve this. Here is the code in the .m file

```
- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UIView* hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView != nil)
    {
        [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
    }
    return hitView;
}

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    CGRect rect = self.bounds;
    BOOL isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point);
    if(!isInside)
    {
        for (UIView *view in self.subviews)
        {
            isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, point);
            if(isInside)
                break;
        }
    }
    return isInside;
}
```

Hopefully this can be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your tapgesture implemenation & the method called.Have a look & check whether it work or not.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[calloutView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[view addSubview:calloutView];


- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"it works");
}
```

Comment: Thank for your post. I actually have specified numberOfTapsRequired=1, forgot to copy paste it. now updated. As I said, even the button on the calloutView doesn't work, so I think the problem shouldn't be that simple.